# sxl: How to check if a row has particular column value?

Tags: xslt

I have a code that return each row, but how can i filter them based on one of the returned column values?

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Sqls/Stuff/Row">
              <tr>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="First" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Second" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Third" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Fourth" />
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

So how can i make this code return only rows where "Third" equals to "SHOWTHIS"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Sqls/Stuff/Row[Third='SHOWTHIS']">
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what i looked for.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the tr in an xsl:if block and test the value of //Sqls/Stuff/Row/Third

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256209.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to check whether all possible "Rows" have that value - if at least one "Third" is "SHOWTHIS", then all rows show up, otherwise - none do.